# Constructing ImageView with style results in width and height of 0

Tags: android, styles, imageview

I created two styles called bullet_normal and bullet_active. I am adding instances of these bullets as ImageViews to a LinearLayout. When I add them in the XML like so, everything works fine:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bar_bullets"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="@dimen/gsbar_height"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp" android:padding="3dp">
    <ImageView style="@style/bullet_normal"></ImageView>
    <ImageView style="@style/bullet_active"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I need the ability add these to the LinearLayout programmatically. I'm trying to it like so:

```
    ImageView normal = new ImageView(this.getContext(), null, R.style.bullet_normal)
    ,       active =  new ImageView(this.getContext(), null, R.style.bullet_active);
    bulletContainer.addView(active);
    bulletContainer.addView(normal);
```

But this always results in ImageViews with width and height equal to 0. The code for both styles is similar to this:

```
   <style name="bullet_normal">
       <item name="android:layout_width">10dip</item>
       <item name="android:layout_height">10dip</item>
       <item name="android:src">@drawable/gsbar_bullet</item>
       <item name="android:layout_margin">6dip</item>
       <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
   </style>
```

And the drawables look like:

```
<shape android:shape="oval"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/gsbar_bullet" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/gsbar_bullet_border" />
</shape>
```

Do I need to change my bullet_normal and bullet_active styles, or am I constructing the ImageViews incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should probably mention that the code adding and removing the bullets is inside of a Bar class that extends RelativeLayout.

Comment: What you could do is introduce a layout which has your bullet ``ImageView`` as root element - nothing more. Then you can create bullets on the fly using ``LayoutInflater``.